# Is it possible to retrieve a record from parse.com without knowing the objectId

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

See the sample code below - in this case, the objectId for the record I am trying to retrieve is known.

My question is, if I don't know the Parse.com objectId, how would I implement the code below?

```
var Artwork = Parse.Object.extend("Artwork");
var query = new Parse.Query(Artwork);
query.get(objectId, {
  success: function(artwork) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    // do something with it
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // warn the user
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to get any `Artwork` record? And how many? One, two, all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use [Parse Query](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide/#queries) to search for objects based on their properties.

Comment: Thanks @hector-ramos....I've seen those instructions but I can't figure it out. Perhaps you could help me by showing my how to solve the problem with the above code...i.e. how would your write this code if you did not know the objectId? I'm struggling with it.

Comment: alternatively, how do you find the objectId when you know one other value for the object?

Comment: It's covered by the iOS Guide under Queries. If you know any property about the object, you can craft a query that says "return only objects that have 'name' equal to 'Héctor'" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Query.**get()** is used when you already know the Parse object id.
Otherwise, one can use query.**find()** to get objects based on the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that wasn't clear to me in the documentation is that once you get the object in the query, you would need to do:

With Query (can return multiple objects):

```
artwork[0].get('someField');
```

With 'first' or 'get':

```
artwork.get('someField');
```

You cannot do something like `artwork.someField` like I assumed you would